# Print List of Github Issues

Tags: github, cappuccino

Is there a way to print out a list of Github issues? Other than by printing the HTML page.

I've tried using the [GitHub Issues Cappuccino App](http://cappuccino.org/discuss/2010/05/13/github-issues-cappuccino-app-desktop-and-web/). I got the app working in Chrome, but it never finishes loading the issues.  I thought it might be because my repo is private, but I can't get it to finish loading issues from a public repo either.

Has anyone found a good way to do this?

Comment: I am the author of the app. It's broken because GitHub disabled their V2 API. However, the app is open source: http://github.com/cappuccino/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of weeks ago I stumbled upon this blog article: http://www.fullo.net/blog/2012/06/25/export-github-issues-as-csv-with-v3-api/. It explains how to grab the issues via a command line curl call to the new API and stuff them into a csv file suing a simple php script. It's the easiest solution I've found so far.

Answer (score -1):

I have a script to export github issues to a CSV file, which you could then print. It's at https://github.com/josephhainline/export_github_issues_to_csv

Feel free to fork it and modify to suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I've never played with Ruby before, but I might give it a try.